# How to set android:orientation="horizontal" programmatically in RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

How to set android:orientation="horizontal" programatically in RelativeLayout like so:

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/ID"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is what I have so far:

```
RelativeLayout rLayout = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());
LayoutParams layoutParams;
layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
rLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As you can see in [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html), there is no `orientation` argument for `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: since the ecplise IDE didn't give any error or warnings I thought it is necessary. and also i didn't get errors at runtime

Comment: Yes. For more informations (and understanding why orientation is useless), you may want to read the Relative Layout Guide by Android Developer reference at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html

Comment: I agree it makes no sense using orientation in RelativeLayout. Just wanted to remark that the Android Studio IDE also gives no warning.

Answer (score 3):

A RelativeLayout layout does not have orientation. Maybe what you need is a LinearLayout.