# Android RelativeLayout clickable overlay view

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm changing a layout to use a RelativeLayout rather than complex nested LinerLayouts - but I've run into some trouble with getting a OnClickListener for a View to work.

I've tried the usual stuff - bring to front, set clickable, setting focusable/focusableInTouchMode to true and false, nothing seems to be working for me.   Hopefully I've just made a silly mistake and you guys can help me out :D

Here's my code:

Layout:
< removed, see edit >

Custom base adapter:
 < removed, turns out its just a layout issue >

The layout is for a row item in a list adapter, and I need to make only half of the row clickable, as the other half has it's own toggles (which are working correctly).

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!!

EDIT: This is strange - I changed it from View to TextView, set a background colour, and now it's showing up - but it's not following the relative layout settings:

```
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/toggle"
```

Specifically it doesn't align with the top as it should. But the clicking works! Now to just get it to cover all the way to the top...

EDIT2:

Updated layout code:

< removed, see later edit >

EDIT3:

The orange is clickView - I want it to extend to the top of each row.

[image]

EDIT4: (changed title)

Ok I've got it working properly now, with the clickView covering the row top to bottom of the left side (and without using specific height/widths).
Here's the current layout code, let me know if there's something I should be doing differently/any improvements you can think of!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View android:id="@+id/fakeView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/clickView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/toggle"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pokemonTypes" />
       <!-- android:background="#ffff914e" -->

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="001"
        android:id="@+id/pokemonNumber"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Bulbasaur"
        android:id="@+id/pokemonName"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pokemonNumber"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/fakeView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Grass"
        android:id="@+id/pokemonTypes"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pokemonName"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pokemonNumber"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/fakeView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/pokemonImage"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fakeView" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggle"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/check1"
        android:textOn=""
        android:textOff=""
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/toggle2" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggle2"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/check2"
        android:textOn=""
        android:textOff=""
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/toggle3" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggle3"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/check3"
        android:textOn=""
        android:textOff=""
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

One other thing I'd like to do - add a larger space to the right of the toggles (margin possibly?) so that when scrolling the fast scroll bar doesn't cover the toggle.  Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you have `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` and `android:focusable="false"`?

Comment: Leftover from trying them - I set them both true, one true, the other true...etc, with no success.  It doesn't work without them either

Comment: @joaquin I am looking for testers...

Comment: Thanks for the nice pix. I guess you're a Pokemon Master. My kid wants it.  Does this mean you're a young Android developer (under 20)?

Comment: I have to compliment on your nice GUI looks and icon images. But we'll have to work on a manageable layout.

Comment: @mmyum, To attract more attention to your question, you can tag it "android-layout" also. I also monitor that specific tag since I want to be an expert at it. If you do so, then perhaps the posted answers can get more attention and more inputs, for bad or good, hehe.

Comment: @TheOriginalAndroid Haha thanks, well I'm trying to make the best Pokedex available on Android.  Glad you like it's look. I'm actually in my mid 20s, but I grew up with Pokemon and have just recently started playing again, decided I needed a better app and so here we are. And yup, I'll tag with android-layout now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample layout based on your responses. It is not exactly like your original layout, but I try to make it similar when applicable. Please be careful and compare what is missing as a difference. It looks almost perfect in the Designer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/fakeView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/clickView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/info"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/info"
        android:background="#ffff914e" />

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pokemonNumber"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="001"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pokemonName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/fakeView"

            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/pokemonNumber"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pokemonNumber"
            android:text="Bulbasaur"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pokemonTypes"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"

            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:text="Grass"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pokemonImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fakeView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggle"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"

            android:text="Toggle"

            android:textOn=""
            android:textOff=""
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="5dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Notes:

1. A nested LinearLayout is used to set some UI elements in a horizontal orientation/view. And I gave it an ID for reference.
2. For clickView, layout_alignBottom and layout_alignTop is used. I think layout_alignParentTop and its bottom is useless for your needs.
3. The **layout_height** of clickView is **wrap_content**, no need to set a specific height which may not look good in different screen resolutions.
4. The Textview pokemonTypes is after the LinearLayout so that it is vertical, relative to pokemonName.

Overall the layout may not be perfect to your specifications. I think it's a good start.

Another good idea is to use **layout_weight** attribute but so far I think you don't need it. layout_weight avoids using specific values. Remember I try to prevent using specific values, hoping to avoid issues with screen resolutions.

Comment: @Piyush, When it's a logical time, I'll remove the other answer. We need to keep the comments.

Comment: @TheOriginalAndroid Thanks, I appreciate all your help!  I was acutally using LinearLayouts before, with layout_weight values -- but when scrolling through the list on older devices I was getting stuttering. I believe the stuttering was related to nested LinearLayouts - so now I've been trying to keep the view hierarchy more shallow (before it was 3 deep) in an effort to improve performance, hence the switch to RelativeLayouts.

Comment: @TheOriginalAndroid OK I've got your sample layout in Android Studio now, a few things -- 1: I don't think that RelativeLayout has an argument for orientation [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20458542/how-to-set-relativelayout-androidorientation-horizontal-programmatically) -- 2: Items inside a LinearLayout don't respect the arguments for RelativeLayouts like layout_alignRight, layout_toRightOf, layout_alignParentLeft - so fakeView becomes useless, and thus pokemonName fills the entire row, pushing the pokemonImage and the toggles off screen

Comment: @TheOriginalAndroid -- 3: clickView looks good, but it doesn't cover pokemonTypes so the user could click on a list item and it won't catch it, if the user clicks on the bottom part of the list item.  Also, it covers the whole width, so if we fix it to show the toggles they will also be covered, preventing the user from toggling them. 

/---/ I agree, I also try to avoid using specific values whenever possible.  I'll try making some changes and see if I can get it to fit my needs.  Thank you again, appreciate all the time you've put into helping me.

Comment: I have to admit that I did not know the various attributes layout_xyz is no longer useful in LinearLayout. This gives me a new perspective on RelativeLayout.

Comment: I know you want to avoid nested layouts, understandable to me. I think you cannot blame slow performance on nested layouts by itself. I have seen others do complicated nested layouts and they do not complain about performance. Perhaps layout_weight, which I have used n like, made your app slow.

Comment: Anyway, I edit my answer to add another (I know) nested LinearLayout with orientation="vertical" so that the Pokemon name and its type is vertically aligned. And it actually looked bit better. I also removed orientation for the RelativeLayout.  I probably won't update my answer anymore, best I can do, but I learned. Click on the helpful icon if you think so.  Good luck...